# Excel - automatically generate list of dates, given multiple date ranges in one column

Tags: excel, date, transpose, date-range

I better show you. This is how my list looks like:

[image]

And this is how I want it to be:

[image]

Basically, in the first picture I have different date ranges, for each date range I have a those two metrics, Sessions and Users and the final result should be a sort of explosion of all date ranges into single dates, considering that certain dates can be included in more than 1 date ranges (e.g. date 2017-08-12) is included in both first and second row.
And last but no least, the end date shouldn´t be counted.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks a million

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the outline of a solution:

1. Split each from/to date in your input table into its 2 constituent dates. You will need to use the string functions (`LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `MID`) to extract the numbers for the  year, month and day values. These will still be strings of characters, so use the `VALUE` function to convert them to actual numbers and then use the `DATE` function to assemble them into a proper date value in Excel. (You may need to format your results using a date format, as Excel stores its dates as number of days since 01/01/1900, so 11/08/2017 is held in Excel as 42958.) Add as many helper columns as you need to your input table to achieve this.
2. Subtract 1 from each end date, this corrects the dates ranges so that the end date is included.
3. The first start date and the last end date define the range of output dates. So start your output table with the first date and in the cell below use a formula to add 1 to this date and copy the formula downwards until you get to your last possible output date.
4. To get the results for each possible output date, you need to find
   which date ranges it belongs to. It belongs to a date range if it is
   greater than or equal to the range's start date and less than or
   equal to the end date. However, rather than comparing each output
   date with individual start and end dates it is possible to compare
   each output date with all the start and all the end dates at once. An expression such as `A10>=E2:E7` generates an array of 6 elements with values
   `TRUE` and `FALSE` according to whether A10 is greater than or equal to
   `E2`, `E3`, `E4`, `E5`, `E6` and `E7` respectively. So, you can use this approach to generate an array of `TRUE`/`FALSE`values showing whether a particular output date is greater than or equal to (ie on or after) each range's start date. Similarly, you can get an array showing whether the same output date is less than or equal to (ie on or before) each range's end date.
5. The versatile `SUMPRODUCT` function can now be used to combine the arrays and the relevant sessions/users values from the input table to get the relevant values for the output date. For example, if the start dates are in `E2:E7`, the end dates in `F2:F7`, the sessions in `B2:B7`  and the output date in `A10` then a sutable formula for determining the number of sessions to attribute to the output date would be `=SUMPRODUCT(($A10>=$E$2:$E$7)*($A10<=$F$2:$F$7)*(B$2:B$7))`. This formula could be copied to give results for all output dates and, assuming the input data for users is in `C2:C7`, it will also give the results for users if copied into the column adjacent to the sessions results. In this formula, the  `TRUE` and `FALSE` values are effectively converted to `1` and `0`, respectively.

A few points: (i) if you don't know how dates work in Excel then find out, it makes tasks such calculating the number of days between two dates or the date n days before/after a particular date extremely easy using simple arithmetic; (ii) don't confuse strings of text which look like dates with dates that can be manipulated arithmetically in Excel; (iii) I believe there are some errors in your example - 16/08/2017 is a date in two of your input ranges and should have results of (2,2) not (1,1) and 17/08/2017 is similarly in error.

I have used this approach in the illustration below and, to test its robustness, I have added an extra row of input data which has sessions different from users and which yields one date (19/08/2017) which does not match to any input range.

[image: Screenshot]

The output date range was generated as follows:

- Cell A10: use formula =E2
- Cell A11: use formula =1+A2
- Cells A12, A13, ... copy formula in cell A11

Comment: Thanks much DDM. It works somehow, however, do you maybe know how to automatically generate output dates as well?

Ideally, all dates included in the different ranges should be listed under Output Date

Comment: If this answer worked for you please mark it as correct.